# How to write the node script to fetch the products and stock in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I am learning Shopify now.

I created an app and a test store, installed the app on the test store and added 5 products for test.
I am writing node script for fetching products and stock from getting access token.
How can I write this script code?
Can you help me with your code snippet written before?